# hadoop job tracker not start on windows 8?

Tags: xml, apache, hadoop

my error log :

2014-04-08 19:05:40,123 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Incorrect header or version mismatch from 127.0.0.1:64570 got version 47 expected version 4
2014-04-08 19:05:40,262 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Setting safe mode to false. Requested by : jayesh
2014-04-08 19:05:40,334 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /C:/jena-Hbase/hadoop-1.2.1-bin/hadoop-1.2.1/tmp/mapred/system from hdfs://localhost:50000/C:/jena-Hbase/hadoop-1.2.1-bin/hadoop-1.2.1/tmp/mapred/system is not a valid DFS filename.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.initialize(JobTracker.java:1757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.offerService(JobTracker.java:2147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4711)

2014-04-08 19:05:40,336 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG:

my hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>C:/jena-Hbase/hadoop-1.2.1-bin/hadoop-1.2.1/data</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>C:/jena-Hbase/hadoop-1.2.1-bin/hadoop-1.2.1/name</value>
</property>


</configuration>
```

please help us to make it working..

Comment: Are you running Hortonworks Hadoop for Windows distribution?

Comment: no I am running with opensource and download from http://hadoop.apache.org/

Comment: Apache Hadoop distribution is generally unsupported on Windows.  You can try running it through Cygwin if you want to use it as a development platform, but running directly on Windows will not work.